# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

I'm creating a command on discord.py with the on_message function
But when I run the command it gives me the following error:
`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'`

This is the code:

```
@client.command(name='test1')
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startwith('!test1'):
    await message.send('This is a test')
```

I tried to search online for some solution but it seems like no one had the same error as me

Answer (score 0):

When you define a command, the first parameter of the function is always the Context object, which represents the context in which a command is being invoked under. The Context object does not have a content attribute.

Try the following:

```
@client.command(name='test1')
async def test1(ctx):
    await ctx.send('This is a test')
```